# Wrap text around image in rich textbox control

Tags: image, vb6, richtextbox

Ok, basically i have a vb6 app and i want to wrap the text in a rich text box around an image i have inserted into the rich text box from the clipboard. At the moment when you insert an image, the text does not wrap around the image...

let me know if you need a screenshot of what i am trying to explain.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

C# version but you might be able to extrapolate:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/csexrichtextbox.aspx

Comment: Jasonk, that code is only to insert an image into a rtf via the clipboard, nothing to do with formatting text around an image... cheers for trying tho.